# criação de uma PK composta

Tags: sql, sql-server, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária, chave-composta

Possuo duas tabelas: **tbl1** e **tbl2**. Na **tbl1** possuo uma `pk` e na **tbl2** possuo uma `FK` que faz referencia a `PK` da **tbl1** e uma `pk`. Com isto, é possível eu fazer uma `pk` composta para a **tbl2** com esses 2 campos ?

EX: 
tabela `cliente` com campos `(id cliente (pk), nome, idade)`

tabela `produto` com campos `(id cliente(fk), id produto (pk), nome, valor)`

gostaria de criar uma `PK` composta na tabela produto usando a `FK` e a `PK`

espero ter deixado claro minha duvida  :v .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Você precisa remover a constraint PK atual e adicionar uma nova PK.

```sql
alter table produto drop CONSTRAINT <nome_constraint>
```

```sql
alter table produto add primary key (id_cliente, id_produto)
```

Para saber o nome da constraint pode utilizar a query abaixo:

```sql
select OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NomeConstraint
FROM sys.objects
where OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)='produto'
and type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
```

Comment: Esse é o melhor método

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Em outro cenário eu poderia usar 2 FK para criação de uma PK composta correto  ?

Comment: @GabrielSilva Sim

Comment: Se a resposta tiver sido útil, dê upvote. Se tiver resolvido o problema, marque como correta. Isso ajuda futuros usuários com o mesmo problema a identificar como resolver. :)